# MIPS instructions of nor

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, mips, bitwise-operators

I'm new to MIPS instructions.
Question is after executing below MIPS instructions, calculate the integer value of `v0` register

```
nor $v0, $a1, $s4
```

given the register values `$a1` = 75, `$s4` = 57. The result I got is `1111....1110000100`, a 2's complement 32 bits binary value equals to decimal value of -124. But the textbook shows the answer is 132. I can't figure out the reason. Please help.

Comment: The correct result for `~(75 | 57)` is `0xffffff84`, which as a 2's complement bit-pattern represents `-124`, so you're right, and your textbook is wrong unless the're talking about different inputs.  IDK where they got 0x84 (132) from.

Comment: Got it, Thank you!

Comment: Which textbook?  posting an answer is probably most useful if future searchers looking for clues about something confusing in a textbook might include the name of the text.

Comment: It's the text book of my data science master degree course, probably the answer for one of the exercise questions given is wrong

Comment: So you're not going to post the title of the textbook?  I don't care about the name of the course it's for, and neither will anyone else searching for how `nor` works in a different course using the same textbook.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I guess I should call it the course notes. It's on the module's teaching material, not a specific textbook.